# Run exe with multiple arguments containing spaces and double quotes

Tags: vb.net

From my code I want to launch another application with 2 arguments that may or may not contain spaces and/or double quotes.

How would I do this?

For example:

```
Dim MyArgs As String
Dim SomeData as string
Dim MyArg1 As String = "First Argument"
Dim MyArg2 As String = "Second Argument" & chr(34) & SomeData & chr(34) & "more text"

MyArgs = MyArg1 & MyArg2

Process.Start(Myapp.exe, MyArgs)
```

Is it possible to pass such a string as an argument, regardless of how many spaces or double quotes it contains?

Comment: You're going to need a delimiter (a space) between arg1 and arg2... otherwise, how will the receiving application parse them?

Comment: There in an example of doing this on the [`ProcessStartInfo.Arguments`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments.aspx) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include a double quote in a VB string literal then just escape it with another double quote, e.g.

```
Process.Start(App.exe, "arg1 ""arg 2"" arg3")
```

As with any other string, you can use concatenation:

```
Process.Start(App.exe, "arg1 """ & arg2 & """ arg3")
```

or call `String.Format`:

```
Process.Start(App.exe, String.Format("arg1 ""{0}"" arg3", arg2))
```

or use string interpolation:

```
Process.Start(App.exe, $"arg1 ""{arg2}"" arg3")
```